# javascript error [jsonFlickrApi is not defined]

Tags: javascript, json, api, flickr

I call a FLickrAPI that returns a `xmlhttp.responseText` that looks like this:

```
jsonFlickrApi({"photos":{"page":1, "pages":200, "perpage":100, "total":"19934",
 "photo":[{"id":"7315581986", "owner":"62691288@N00", "secret":"504915125a", 
"server":"7090", "farm":8, "title":"China, Tiananmen Square", "ispublic":1,
 "isfriend":0, "isfamily":0}, {"id":"7308693706",
...
```

i try to parse it like this:

```
var jsonResponse = xmlhttp.responseText ;
jsonResponse = eval("("+jsonResponse + ")");
var output += jsonResponse.photos.photo[1].id ;
alert(output);
```

Firebug tells me: `jsonFlickrApi is not defined`

- why do i get this error message?
- why do i have to use 'eval' in the first place?

Comment: Are you correctly importing the .js file that contains the jsonFlickrApi() function? Please post that code and any other that would give us a more complete picture.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you get a [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)-response to your request, not a JSON-response. [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) is a JSON-object, wrapped in a function call. So just define the function `jsonFlickrApi`, and it will be called when the response is available:

```
function jsonFlickrApi (response) {
  console.log(
     "Got response from Flickr-API with the following photos: %o", 
     response.photos
  );
  // Handle the response here. I.E update the DOM, trigger event handlers etc.
}

// Later in your XMLHttpRequest code:
var jsonResponse = xmlhttp.responseText ;
// This will call the jsonFlickrApi-function.
eval("("+jsonResponse + ")");
```